# SQL Problema al combinar min con group by en una consulta de varios registros

Tags: sql

Estoy seguro de que es una pregunta muy sencilla, así que voy a explicarla con tablas de *excel* para no tener que crear una tabla nueva en la *base de datos*.

Básicamente, lo que busco es que, a partir de una tabla como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Sacar los datos del número mas pequeño de cada **Id**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

He hecho esto:

```
Select Id, MIN(Numero) AS Numero, Nombre from Tabla group by Id, Nombre
```

Y me saca la misma tabla de arriba **es decir, todos los registros** porque estoy agrupando con el nombre también ya que el propio SQL me obliga a agrupar con él.

A mí me gustaría poder hacer algo así:

```
Select Id, MIN(Numero) AS Numero, Nombre from Tabla group by Id
```

¿Hay algún modo de hacer una sola sentencia que saque la segunda tabla? o, ¿alguna forma de no tener que agrupar también por el nombre?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esto es relativamente simple de lograr usando `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT Id, Numero, Nombre
FROM (
       SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY Id ORDER BY Numero) RN
       FROM Tabla
     ) t
WHERE RN = 1
;
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me viene perfecto